# How to print plain text using Monodevelop and C#?

Tags: c#, macos, monodevelop

I have some text displayed in a TextView which I want to print. I've been googling for 2 whole hours now. If anyone could help me out with this, you'd really make my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code on this page excellently explains how this can be done:
http://www.mail-archive.com/gtk-sharp-list@lists.ximian.com/msg03762.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very simple example (tested on a Windows machine):

```
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
var printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
doc.PrintPage += (s, ev) => {
        ev.Graphics.DrawString("Your text goes here",
                                printFont, 
                                Brushes.Black, 
                                ev.MarginBounds.Left,
                                ev.MarginBounds.Top);
        HasMorePages = false;
    };
doc.Print();
```

You'll have to add a reference to `System.Drawing` and these two `using` statements :

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
```

Comment: I saw this in another example. The `System.Drawing` namespace doesn't exist on MonoDevelop for Mac.

Comment: You need to add a reference to System.Drawing.dll

Comment: @Nacereddine You can update your answer using a rectangle definition in order to support long text with word wrap -- DrawString(String, Font, Brush, RectangleF)