# Print a jpeg image or Gdk.Pixbuf with a printing dialog using monodevelop C#

Tags: c#, printing, gtk, jpeg, monodevelop

I am trying to print either a Gdk.Pixbuf or (after it saves as a jpeg) printing the jpeg file to a printer. I want the user to be able to open a print dialog native to either windows or linux or use the gdk one. I couldn't get any examples I found to work as they used different libraries and commands than what I have available.

Here is the code I used to generate the jpeg:

```
Gdk.Window window = Gdk.Global.ActiveWindow;
    if (window!=null)
    {           
        int windowX;
        int windowY;
        window.GetSize (out windowX, out windowY);
        Console.WriteLine (windowX + " " + windowY);
        Gdk.Pixbuf pixBuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(Gdk.Colorspace.Rgb, false, 8, windowX, windowY);          
        pixBuf.GetFromDrawable(window, Gdk.Colormap.System, 0, 0, 0, 0, windowX, windowY);
        pixBuf.Save("../screenshot.jpeg", "jpeg");
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459685/how-to-print-image-with-gtksharp

Comment: I wasn't able to use any of that code. Cairo isn't in my project and I cannot install the nuget package due to compatibility issues with my project targeting .net 4.5. I will continue to look but haven't been able to find anything else that will work well. I don't have to save/print jpeg directly but possibly the pixBuf.